# Unassigning content rule throws traceback error in Plone 4.2

Tags: plone

I have about 15 content rules set up on a Plone 4.2 site, those rules are assigned to various folders.

I was recently doing a bit of tidying up and removing some unneeded rules, but I get a traceback when trying to Unassign any rule.

How the traceback occurrs:

- Go into rules tab
- Tick rule
- Press `Unassign`

I receive:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.contentrules.browser.assignments, line 57, in __call__
KeyError: '/mysite/aFolder/aSubFolder'
```

I seem to be able to assign rules without issue, it is just unassigning them once I have assigned them that's the problem.

If it helps my rules work as follows:

- Content state changed to pending
- Send an email to a person

Any information or ideas as to what this Traceback is trying to tell me, or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT #1**

The only thing that has changed since the rules were originally assigned is I upgraded TinyMCE to the latest version, besides that no add-ons have been installed or any changes have been made to the server.

**EDIT #2**

It seems that this error only occurs on certain folders on my site - I have managed to unassign a rue from one so far, however I can see the rules in mysite.com/@@rules-controlpanel and am able to see which folders they are assigned to.

Comment: Did you perhaps *rename* `/mysite/aFolder` or `/mysite/aFolder/aSubFolder` in the past? Do you get redirected when you visit either path?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was renamed, however I believe this was before the rule was applied to it. No I can access both aFolder and aSubFolder with no redirects. It seems to be happening to about 50% of the folders I have tried. I have just disabled the rules for the time being on those folders, although I fear the customer may get worried upon trying to unassign them and seeing errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on a 4.3 site, in an object that was copied/moved multiple times...

**Short story**

I disabled the rule modifying the line 57 (the one the Traceback points out):

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.contentrules.browser.assignments, line 57, in __call__
KeyError: '/mysite/aFolder/aSubFolder'
```

from this:

```
get_assignments(storage[r]).remove(path, None)
```

to this:

```
if path in assignments:
    get_assignments(storage[r]).remove(path, None)
```

** Long story **

The patch was applied overriding the manage-content-rules view.
This is the needed zcml

```
<browser:page
  for="plone.contentrules.engine.interfaces.IRuleAssignable"
  name="manage-content-rules"
  class=".contentrules_patch.PatchedManageAssignments"
  layer="my.abb.browser.interfaces.IMyAppLayer"
  permission="plone.app.contentrules.ManageContentRules"
/>
```

and this is the class contained in contentrules_patch.py

```
class PatchedManageAssignments(ManageAssignments):
    def __call__(self):
        """
        """
        request = aq_inner(self.request)
        form = request.form

        if not 'form.button.Delete' in form:
            return super(PatchedManageAssignments, self).__call__()

        context = aq_inner(self.context)
        assignable = IRuleAssignmentManager(context)
        storage = getUtility(IRuleStorage)
        status = IStatusMessage(self.request)
        rule_ids = form.get('rule_ids', ())
        path = '/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath())

        for r in rule_ids:
            del assignable[r]
            assignments = get_assignments(storage[r])
            if path in assignments:
                get_assignments(storage[r]).remove(path, None)
        status.addStatusMessage(_(u"Assignments deleted."), type='info')
        return self.template()
```